# Changing colors and styling of collection_select dropdown with rails bootstrap and select2 implemented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, select2-rails

I want to change the colors and style a dropdown in rails to match the rest of my web app styling. I am using Rails, Bootstrap, and select2 and I have no idea where to add css and how to even begin accessing the the different parts of the dropdown so that I can color them and make them fit with the rest of the design on the app.

this is the implementation of  the dropdown

```
<%= collection_select(:id, :name, @product, :id, :name,{:include_blank => true},{class: "js-example-basic-single" }) %>
```

Please advise me on how to accomplish styling this item, thanks.

Comment: Changing font, colors, arrows etc.. how do you access these components in the css ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your question is so I will try to answer it as best as I can. I believe you should be adding your CSS to the application.css file that should be under app\assets\stylesheets. Then if you want to customize all your dropdowns the same you can use the `select` tag in css. Here is an example

```css
select {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 2px;
}
    
select:hover {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick update

adding the below worked for me... suprising this isnt in the bootstrap gem

```
select {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
```